# excel external links to closed workbooks in many folders

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a working external reference in excel like this

```
='T:\Assessment and Feedback\11WRooney\[y7 a+f.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$2
```

but I want the link to use a cell reference instead of one of the directories for part of the reference

I thought something like this would allow me to use the contents of cell A2 as the folder name so I could autofill down.

```
='T:\Assessment and Feedback\'&A2&'\[y7 a+f.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$2
```

I can get it working using this(below) but it stops when I close the file being referenced - and the files will be closed

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'","T:\Assessment and Feedback\", A2,"\[y7 a+f.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$2"))
```

Any suggestions much appreciated